# Outlook Email loses left padding

Tags: css, outlook, email-templates

I know it is very common issue but I've tried all the recommended solutions and nothing worked.

The email template I have loses left margin in outlook browser. I want to add the left margin/padding only for outlook and let it be ignored in other browsers as they look fine and do not need extra margin. I need to fix it with inline css only without any styling in . I do not use any margin or padding in my css.

Here is my code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="598" style="width: 598px;">
        <tr>
            <td><span style="width:45px;height:20px;"><div style="width:25px;height:20px;">&nbsp;</div></span></td>
            <td>
                <span style="width:45px;height:15px;"><div style="width:25px;height:15px;">&nbsp;</div></span>
                <div>some text</div>
                <span style="width:45px;height:15px;"><div style="width:25px;height:15px;">&nbsp;</div></span>
                <div>some text</div>
                <span style="width:45px;height:20px;"><div style="width:25px;height:20px;">&nbsp;</div></span>
                <div>some text</div>
                <span style="width:45px;height:40px;"><div style="width:25px;height:20px;">&nbsp;</div></span>
                <div>some text,</div>
                <span style="width:45px;height:20px;"><div style="width:25px;height:20px;">&nbsp;</div></span>
                <div>some text</div>
                <span style="width:45px;height:5px;"><div style="width:25px;height:5px;">&nbsp;</div></span>
            </td>
            <td><span style="width:45px;height:20px;"><div style="width:25px;height:20px;">&nbsp;</div></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried adding padding to each td element but while it fixes view in outlook it adds extra padding in other browsers. Adding `&nbsp;` gives the same results.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try margin:auto??

Comment: As far as I know margin is ignored by outlook

Comment: yes you're right! but did you tried playing with "cellpadding and cellspacing" on the table Tag?

Comment: i did and it changed padding for all browsers, I need to change for outlook only

Answer (score -2):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="598" style="width: 598px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:100%;padding-left:10px">
               <tr>
                 <td>
                   <table>
                     <!-- your content here-->
                   </table>
                 </td>
               </tr>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Try wrapping the content in the main **td** and style it. This will enforce the padding on the entire email body. I have tried this approach and has worked for me. Give it a try and let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you, though this didn't solve the issue - it adds extra padding to all browsers, not only outlook

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Why do u think so?

Comment: I believe this approach is used in standard responsive email templates. 

@ksenia0822 Yes you are right, it adds padding in all the browsers. One change you have to make sure is to add your table in the inner most td when I say <!-- your content here -->

Comment: A `<tr>` cannot be a direct child of a `<td>`.

Comment: You are right Mike. That's the reason in my above comment I mention to add `<table>` inside the main wrapper `<td>`. Thanks for pointing!  For users benefit I am going to edit my answer as well.